# Global regex match timeout works in console application, but not in ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: .net, regex, asp.net-mvc, appdomain

I'm trying to use .NET 4.5's new [regular expression match timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matchtimeout.aspx), specifically the global variant via `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData` with the `"REGEX_DEFAULT_MATCH_TIMEOUT"` property (the variant whereby you pass a `TimeSpan` to the regex constructor works fine).

When I create a new console application with this main method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("REGEX_DEFAULT_MATCH_TIMEOUT",
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

    var m = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "^(x+x+)+y$");
}
```

it works as expected: After three seconds, it throws a `RegexMatchTimeoutException`.

However if I create an empty MVC 4 app, add a `HomeController` and this action method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("REGEX_DEFAULT_MATCH_TIMEOUT",
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

    var m = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "^(x+x+)+y$");

    return View();
}
```

and visit `http://localhost:XXXXX/` no exception is thrown and the match attempt continues. (If you wait long enough, it'll eventually finish, and then complain about the missing view. That takes *veeery* long though.)

Calling `SetData` in `Global.asax`'s `Application_Start()` instead of within the controller action doesn't make the timeout happen either.

Comment: Could you try to initialize new regex object http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160196.aspx and try to set Match Timeout only for this regex? If it will not work too - I will suggest you to submit a bug on https://connect.microsoft.com/

Comment: @outcoldman As I said in my question, the constructor variant works fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess that difference between these two samples is that in your Console Application second line is the first access to the RegEx object and this is where you initialize this type. In MVC - my guess that RegEx class is used before your Index action.

I tried to verify this behavior with simple Console Application and got the same result as you had in MVC:

```
var m = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(
    "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "x");

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("REGEX_DEFAULT_MATCH_TIMEOUT", 
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

var m2 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(
    "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "^(x+x+)+y$");
```

So, you just need to make sure that you will initialize this property before somebody else will use it. 
You can specify this configuration with web.config: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.defaultregexmatchtimeout.aspx in httpRuntime section.

Comment: Wow, that's... unexpected. Works with web.config indeed -- thanks!